# 'Full authentication is required to access this resource' Clockify API with Node JS

Tags: node.js, https, clockify

I am unable to add new clients using the Clockify API in Node js. The following axios post request returns the error message: 'Full authentication is required to access this resource'. However, I am able to get a list of clients using the axios.get() method with the same API key, so I'm not sure why the post request says I'm not authenticated. Please let me know what I'm missing

```
async function addNewClient(clientName) {
return response = await axios.post(`${url}/workspaces/${workspaceId}/clients`, {
    data: {
        'name': clientName
    },
    headers: {
        'X-Api-Key': CLOCKIFY_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
   
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data.message);
    return
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Regenerating `API_KEY` solved it.